# menu items with submenu switch all content for some pixels to the right

Tags: css

I absolutly know that you will downvote this question, but I cannot repeat this problem in jsfiddle or with custom html, so I can only show it using webpage.

If I understand the problem, I will update question with appropriate html code.

If you visit website http://tax.allfaces.lv/, you will see three menu items. If you click on first or third menu item (Home and Contact US), then everything is fine.

Merchants contains submenu. It is not so obvious, but if you click on second one (Merchants), then you see that the whole content is moved some pixels to the right comparing with Home and Contact Us page. If you just click "Home" and "Merchants" one by one, you can see that for "Merchants" all content is some pixels to the right.

EDIT:
This is related to webpage height and scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your body to keep the scroll bar all the time to avoid this issue

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This works. Can you, please, explaing where does this scrollbar comes from and why it is affected by menu?

Comment: Its not affected by the menu but by your content, Your content is to much to fit in the page, so the browser adds a scrollbar to scroll down. On your homepage however, there is no scrollbar needed becasue the content fits on the page

Comment: It is not affected by the menu, it is because there is a difference between heights on the different pages within the site. Pages that require more than 100% height of your screen size will automatically get a scroll bar to allow you to view content that overflows. Hence the fix 0 overflow-y: scroll which forces every page to be ready to scroll

Answer (score 1):

It's because the scrollbar disappears because all of the content fits in the page :)

Answer (score 1):

its because the scrollbar on the side dispears ;) 
what you could do is show the scrollbar at everypage so it doesnt move.